# I want to remove only the parent tag I clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 3 buttons in my code.

One is to add more files. (`.btn-plus`)
One is to remove the one added. (`.btn-minus`)
One is to reset the file. (`.btn-reset`)

I could add more input with (`.btn-plus`) button.

How could I delete only the one I click among every input I add with (`.btn-plus`)?

```js
$(".btn-plus").click(function(){
    $('.board-box__attachments').prepend('<li><div class="th">files</div><div class="td"><input type="file"><button class="btn btn-minus"> - </button></div></li>');
    return false;
})


$(".btn-minus").click(function(){
      $(this).nextUntil('li').remove()
})


$(".btn-reset").click(function(){
      $(".board-box__attachments input").value = "";
})
```

```css
li {
  width : 60%;
  background : lightblue;
  list-style : none;
  padding : 0.5em;
  border-bottom : 1px solid white;
}

.th { 
  width : 100px;
  float: left;
}

.td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="board-box__attachments">

  <li>
    <div class="th">files</div>
    <div class="td">
      <input type="file">
      <button class="btn btn-plus"> + </button>
      <button class="btn-reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the minus button. You need to use event delegation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).nextUntil("li")` doesn't match anything. It only searches siblings of `this`, and the button doesn't have any `li` siblings. If you want to select the `li` containing the button, use `$(this).closest("li")`.

You also need to use event delegation to bind an event handler to dynamically-created elements.

```js
$(".btn-plus").click(function(){
    $('.board-box__attachments').prepend('<li><div class="th">files</div><div class="td"><input type="file"><button class="btn btn-minus"> - </button></div></li>');
    return false;
})


$(".board-box__attachments").on("click", ".btn-minus", function(){
      $(this).closest("li").remove()
})
```

```css
li {
  width : 50%;
  background : lightblue;
  list-style : none;
  padding : 1em;
  border-bottom : 1px solid white;
}

.th { 
  width : 100px;
  float: left;
}

.td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="board-box__attachments">

  <li>
    <div class="th">files</div>
    <div class="td">
      <input type="file">
      <button class="btn btn-plus"> + </button>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `on()` to attach event to dynamically added element. Then use `closest()` to find currently clicked element's parent.

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn-minus", function(){
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with you code:

1. Your element which contains `btn-minus` is being created dynamically. So the `click` event would not work instead you need to use `on` event.

```
   $(".btn-minus").click(function(){
```

So instead of this you need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-minus', function() {
```

2. Also you need to use following code to remove element.

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

Please see the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqf3412m/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can creating elements dynamically so once the page is loaded, browser has no knowledge of '.btn-minus'

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-minus', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
})
```

Hope this helps!